# Javascript function return value undefined

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, console

I am using a function to go through an array of objects and filter out the one that matches certain criteria.

```
var thread = underscore.find(threads, function (th) {

            function result(threadArray){
                threadArray.forEach(function(threads){
                    if (threads.owner.id === ownerId && threads.name.toLowerCase() == threadName) {
                        console.log(threads)
                        return threads
                    }
                });
            };

            console.log(result(th));
            return th.owner.id === ownerId && th.name.toLowerCase() === threadName;
});
```

'th' is the array of objects. Stepping through it, I can see that the array of objects is being iterated over using the forEach function, and that my if logic is successfully filtering out just one object because I can see it in my console "console.log(threads)", but when I try to console the return value of the function by invoking it, "console.log(result(th))", it comes back as undefined, and I can't figure out why.

[image]

Comment: You aren't returning anything from `result`. You're returning from `.forEach`, which doesn't do anything. Use a standard `for` loop instead. You could also declare a variable *inside* of `result` and *outside* of `forEach` then assign to that variable where you're doing `return threads`. Note that `forEach` doesn't care about your return values at all. It will go over the entire collection no matter what and doesn't return anything.

Comment: You should replace `foreach` function to `filter`: `return threadArray.filter(...)`.

Comment: You're absolutely right. Can't believe I missed that hah. Thanks Mike